# Closed form for the function $f(x)=\ln\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1+a^k}{1+a^{k+x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, infinite-product

Consider the function  $$f(x)=\ln\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1+t^k}{1+t^{k+x}}$$
where $t\in(0,1)$.
According to some theorems I found that $f(x)$ is well defined for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. 
In order to find the closed form for $f$, I dealt to the following equality as follows
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1+(1/2)^k}{1+(1/2)^{k+x}}=\frac{(-1;1/2)_\infty(2^{-x}+1)}{2(-2^{-x};1/2)_\infty}$$
where $t=1/2$ and $(a;q)_n$ gives q-pochhammer symbol.

Is the above equality true? If the answer is yes, how can I compute the exact value of above product, Also can it help to find closed form for $f$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there exists a closed form for this function? Unless $x\in\mathbb{N}$ (in which case the product easily telescopes), I see no reason to think it would, and ample reason to think otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^{\infty} (1 - a \, q^{k}) &= (a;q)_{\infty} \\
\frac{(a;q)_{\infty}}{(a \, q^{n}; q)_{\infty}} &= (a;q)_{n}
\end{align}
then
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1 + t^{k+x}) = (-t^{x+1}; t)_{\infty}$$
which leads to
$$f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+t^{x})}{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1 + t^{k+x})}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{(-t;t)_{\infty}}{(-t^{x+1};t)_{\infty}}\right) = \ln((-t;t)_{x}).$$
when $t=1/2$ then
$$f(x) = \ln\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}\right)_{x}\right).$$
A table of values may be obtained based on the value of $x$.

It is of interest to note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \ln\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty}\right) = .86887665\cdots.$$

Comment: would you lead me that how do you obtain (compute) these result, or

Comment: would you introduce some references which can help me.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi See, for example, [q-Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html)